# Add column GtkTreeView through popup menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

By clicking on any column's header of a GtkTreeView, I want to open a popup menu with a selection items where the user can add or remove columns in runtime.
Below I have the example of a normal GtkTreeView. How do I add this functionality to it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TreeModelSort(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(200, -1)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(["Mark"])
        liststore.append(["Chris"])
        liststore.append(["Tim"])
        liststore.append(["David"])
        liststore.append(["Keith"])
        liststore.append(["Mark"])

        treemodelsort = Gtk.TreeModelSort(liststore)
        treemodelsort.set_sort_column_id(0, Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING)

        treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
        treeview.set_model(treemodelsort)
        self.add(treeview)

        cellrenderertext = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        treeviewcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Name", cellrenderertext, text=0)
        treeview.append_column(treeviewcolumn)

window = TreeModelSort()
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: It's not hard in theory - connect to a click event on the TreeViewColumn and show a popup menu. In practice, though, it fails because for some reason the click events don't seem to work properly on TreeViews and TreeViewColumns...

Comment: Is there this problem in all Gtk Versions?

Comment: It seems you need to set `treeview.set_headers_clickable(True)` and then `treeview.connect('button-press-event', callback)` to make clicks work.

Comment: When you use `headers-clickable` you get [a `clicked` signal on the GtkTreeViewColumn when clicking](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html#GtkTreeViewColumn-clicked). Other than that I'm not sure; sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I am a little too late to respond for OP, but it might help others throughout SEO.

Currently, it is still GTK3 being most conventionally used version whereas GTK4 still being under development. To this point, GTK+ **does not** support adding columns "in real time" with a firsthand approach. That is, it does not support adding columns in the tree view model (GtkListStore in your case) after it is initialized with a given number of column types, but you can insert `GtkTreeViewColumn` objects in the `GtkTreeView` at any time. As it states in the GTK C reference page of `GtkListStore` for the function `gtk_list_store_set_column_types()`:

> This function is meant primarily for GObjects that inherit from
>   GtkListStore, and should only be used when constructing a new
>   GtkListStore. It will not function after a row has been added, or a
>   method on the GtkTreeModel interface is called.

You can create a new list store with the old types plus the new column type, copy row data and then call the treeview method to use that list store.
In C, I take advantage of those functions: `g_object_set_data()`, `g_object_get_data()`, `gtk_list_store_newv()` which you can read and learn what they are used for and where they might be helpful. Don't forget to pack a new `GtkTreeViewColumn` with an appropriate renderer and set its attributes (number of columns).